# angle constrained convex hull

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, convex-hulls

Given a set of points $P$ in $R^d$ it is straightforward to compute the convex hull (Graham-scan etc). However, the angle between the adjacent faces are unconstrained. Let us suppose two adjacent faces with normal $\vec{n}_1$ and $\vec{n}_2$. Let us suppose we want $\vec{n}_1.\vec{n}_1 \leq \cos \alpha$.
(See figure for illustration)
How do we generate such a convex hull ? Which algorithm (with suitable modifications) do I use ?

[Constrained convex hull. The image shows the convex hull of a set of points. Further, a violation on angular constraint is marked. A required conv hull is shown in dashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj8o2.jpg)

Comment: You could delete one of the offending faces and extend the others until they meet.

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Firstly, extending other faces might begin to violate the constraint faces (See figure) [Violation of constraint with other face](https://imgur.com/a/wj9jQwr). Further, there is no guarantee that such an extension would be have a minimal volume.

Comment: I don't understand your figure. Also your posted question does not mention anything about minimal volume.

Comment: I modified the image. [violation with adjacent faces] (https://imgur.com/a/ZReC5QU). The addition of a new vertex should ensure that the angle constraint is still maintained. By minimal volume, I meant the "figure hugging" aspect that a convex hull guarantees.

Comment: That's not what I meant by deleting a face and extending the others. I mean literally erase one of the edges next to your red vertex; now your polygon has a gap in it. Take the edges on either side of the gap and make them longer without changing their direction, until they meet and the gap is closed. Now you have fixed one angle violation. If there are more, repeat the process. (This almost certainly doesn't give the polyhedron with minimal volume satisfying the angle constraints; I'm just clarifying my original comment that was written before you said anything about volume.)